# TableRow contents are going beyond screen size

Tags: android

I have a design problem not sure why it does it and that's why I'm here. Here is the image and the code. Hopefully you guys can help me.

http://i60.tinypic.com/fwr8mh.jpg (Link to image)

```
<TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2:00 [Extended]"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/light" />
        </TableRow>
```

Thank you.

As requested [Current Code]:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2f4f4f" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#36444e" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Brewing:"
                    android:textColor="#ffff00" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#36444e" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ghasttear" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#36444e" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/brewingarrow" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#36444e" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity=""
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/waterbottle" />
            </TableRow>


            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#ffffff" />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Potion Time"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="0:45 [Non-Extended]"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2:00 [Extended]"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:ellipsize="end" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/light" />
            </TableRow>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#ffffff" />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Potion Description"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Poyion time lasts for 0:45 when not extended."
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I can't see the image. The link does not work.

Comment: Is your light drawable very big?

Comment: @joao2fast4u: It's just small. Let me make it larger.

Comment: @joao2fast4u: No it's 32x32dp like all of my other images

Comment: What exactly is going beyond your screen size?

Comment: @joao2fast4u: the ImageView because the textview is eating up all the space for no reason. It's like expanding beyond the screen size of every device. Well as far as the eclipse design android screen goes.

Comment: Then you have to set a fix width to your `TextView`, like 200dp, for example. And ellipsize your text, using `android:ellipsize="end"`.

Comment: @joao2fast4u: It's still not working for some reason.

Comment: @joao2fast4u: XML or Java code?

Comment: XML, assuming you are not manipulation your layout dynamically on runtime.

Comment: Is your Activity layout file just that?

Comment: What is the real length of your text? I couldn't understand.

Comment: @joao2fast4u: What do you mean by real length?

Comment: Are you other drawables also 32x32 or are they bigger? Do you have a size for each density (XXHDPI, HXDPI, HDPI, etc)?

Comment: @joao2fast4u: They are also 32x32px. And I do not have a image specific for a different density type.

Comment: `2:00 [Extended]`, is that the real value or there is more text in this value. I am confused about the Extended word there.

Comment: OK, I spotted your problem? What do you want to happen? Your 2:00 Extended text appears on top of your  light drawable, or on the left of it?

Comment: @joao2fast4u left of it and yea that's real value of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in each `TableRow` component, you can just have one child `View. So, in order to have a`TextView`and an`ImageView`, you have to place those Views inside another View, like a`LinearLayout`or a`RelativeLayout`, so you can control their positions.

So, in your "problematic" `TableRow`, just change it to this:

```
     <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/extendedText"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:text="2:00 [Extended]"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/light" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>
```

I just put the `ImageView` and the `TextView` inside a `RelativeLayout` and aligned the `TextView` to the left of its parent View (which is the RelativeLayout) and the `ImageView` to the right. Never mind the `ellipsize` value if your text won't get too long.